# Laravel Nova Tag field results in 404 on production

Tags: laravel, preview, laravel-nova, tagfield

I seriously cannot wrap my head around this.
Locally the tag field of Laravel Nova 4.0 works like a charm (https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/fields.html#tag-field). On production it results in a 404 page on the resource-detail page.
Everything seems to be the same. Same laravel nova version (4.20.2), same data, same other packages.

I've narrowed it down to this call being sent on production:
Request URL: https://api.foodinfluencersunited.nl/nova-api/tags/23a1f0b3-eaac-45c3-b6da-7c1acda08f9d/preview
Which is not sent locally. This call should either not be sent on production (since the tagField has "withPreview" off, or at least it should be sent to:
Request URL: https://api.foodinfluencersunited.nl/nova-api/roles/23a1f0b3-eaac-45c3-b6da-7c1acda08f9d/preview
Since the uuid which is sent is the UUID of a Role-resource.

Does anyone have any idea where I should search for the solution?

I'm trying to at least get the error locally as well.
Imported the production data to local server and made sure that everything else is similar.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared I had out-of-date js on one of my production servers. `php artisan nova:publish` did not run automatically on one of them. That solved my issue.